# Mean of fractional part of $\log n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, logarithms, asymptotics

Let $\{x\}$ be the fractional part of $x.$ Can we show that

$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N~\{\log n\}= _{\pm}\Omega(1/2)? $$

In case my usage is nonstandard, I mean that the l.h.s. is infinitely often less than and greater than 1/2.

Caveat--I am not sure it's true because I haven't made any headway towards proving it.

(I see that someone has asked a similar question about log n. This isn't quite the same so am posting it.)

Comment: Though some numerical computation and hand waving argument, it seems
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} \left[ \frac1N\sum\limits_{k=1}^N [ \log n ] - f([\log N])\right ] = 0
\quad\text{ where }\quad
f(s) = \frac{e^{1 - s}}{e-1} + s - 1$$ Since $f([0,1]) = \left[ \log\frac{e}{e-1}, \frac{1}{e-1} \right] \approx [ 0.458675, 0.5819767 ]$, the
average do seem to rise above/fall below $\frac12$ infinitely often.

Comment: @achillehui: Would love to see this in gory detail...

Comment: If other people doesn't beat me for this, I will do that tomorrow.

Comment: The fractional part of $x$ (which is what I think you're calling the "decimal part") is usually denoted $\{x\}$. Indeed, $[x]$'s standard meaning is the greatest integer not exceeding $x$, which makes the notation particularly confusing.

Comment: @GregMartin: Thanks, will edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For any real $x$, let $\lfloor x \rfloor \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor \in [0,1)$ be the integer and fractional part of $x$.
For any $x > 1$, the function $\{\log x\}$ is discontinuous at $e, e^2, e^3, \ldots$. Since $e$ is transcendental, this set of numbers is disjoint with $\mathbb{Z}$, the set of discontinuities of the function $\lfloor x \rfloor$. 
Using this fact, the average at hand can be rewritten as a [Riemann Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral)
and integrate by part without any issue.

For any $N > 2$, write $\log N$ as $n + s$ where $n = \lfloor\log N\rfloor$ and $s \in (0,1)$. We have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^N \{\log k\} &= \sum_{k=2}^N \{\log k\}
= \int_{1+}^{N+}\{\log x\} d\lfloor x \rfloor
= \bigg[\{\log x\}\lfloor x \rfloor\bigg]_{1+}^{N+}
- \int_{0+}^{n+s+} \lfloor e^y \rfloor d\{y\}\\
&= Ns -\underbrace{\int_{0+}^{n+s+} e^y d\{y\}}_I
+ \underbrace{\int_{0+}^{n+s+} \{ e^y \} d\{y\}}_J\tag{*1}
\end{align}
$$
For the $2^{nd}$ term, we have

$$\begin{align}I 
&= \int_{0+}^{n+s+} e^y d( y - \lfloor y \rfloor )
= \int_0^{n+s} e^y dy - \sum_{k=1}^n e^k\\
&= e^{n+s} - 1 - \frac{e}{e-1}(e^n-1)
= N\left( 1  - \frac{e^{1-s}}{e-1}\right) + \frac{1}{e-1}
\end{align}\tag{*2}$$
For the $3^{th}$ term, we have

$$J = \int_{n}^{n+s} \{e^y\} dy + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{k+}^{k+1+} \{e^y\} d\{y\}
   = \int_{n}^{n+s} \{e^y\} dy + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_0^1 \left( \{ e^{k+y} \} - \{ e^{k+1} \}\right) dy$$
Notice the magnitude of all the $n+1$ integrands in above expression is bounded from above by $1$. We obtain following bound of $J$.

$$|J| \le \int_n^{n+s} dy + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_0^1 dy = n + s = \log N\tag{*3}$$

Substitute $(*2)$ and $(*3)$ into $(*1)$, we obtain

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N \{\log k\} = f(\{\log N\}) + \epsilon_N
\quad\text{ where }\quad f(s) = \frac{e^{1-s}}{e-1} + s - 1$$
and the error term $\epsilon_N$ satisfies
$$|\epsilon_N| \le \frac1N \left(\log N + \frac{1}{e-1}\right)$$
From this, we can conclude the average at hand oscillate like $f(\{\log N\})$ as $N \to \infty$.

Since
$$f([0,1]) = \left[\log\frac{e}{e-1}, \frac{1}{e-1}\right]
\approx [\;0.458675, 0.5819767\;]$$
the average will oscillate between $0.458675$ and $0.5819767$ and hence below/above $\frac12$ infinitely often.

At the end is a picture plotting the average vs the approximation $f(\{\log N\})$. It clearly shows the average approximately follows $f(\{\log N\})$ even for $N$ as small as $20$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for adding. Yes, it basically agrees. I meant the lower bounds of the average are a little lower than $f$ until (?). In Mathematica the min you have at about 90 for the average is still a little below the range. n=87  is about .45617.

Answer (score 4):

Let $k$ be a nonnegative integer and let $0<\delta<1$. Note that $$\sum_{e^k\le n<e^{k+\delta}} \{\log n\} = \sum_{e^k\le n<e^{k+\delta}} (\log n - k)$$ is a Riemann sum for $$(e^{k+\delta}-e^k) \int_{e^k}^{e^{k+\delta}} (\log t - k)\,dt.$$
Indeed, since the integrand is increasing, the difference between the Riemann sum and the integral itself is bounded by the difference between consecutive sample points (which is $1$ here) and the change in the integrand from one endpoint to the other (which is $\delta<1$ here). Moreover, the value of the integral is
$$
\int_{e^k}^{e^{k+\delta}} (\log t - k)\,dt = \big( t\log t - (k+1)t \big) \bigg|_{e^k}^{e^{k+\delta}} = 
$$
*argh ran out of time, somebody want to finish?*

Comment: Once I saw how you expressed the limits of the sum the idea was clear. My problem is with the lower bound on the average using the integral. (The numerator is the result of inegration): $$\frac{e^k-(1-\delta)e^{k+\delta}}{e^k(e^{\delta}-1)}=[0^+,.58197]$$ This gives same upper bound as achille lui but lower bound of zero (well, zero+).