# Is the mean of $\{\log\log n\} =\Omega(1/2)$?

Tags: number-theory, logarithms, asymptotics

This is basically an exercise to try to extrapolate from an answer to an earlier question.

The answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2278240/mean-of-fractional-part-of-log-n#2279187) and the trick for choosing the limits of a sum of logs [here at pp. 35-36](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/kar/weyl.pdf) suggest that expressing the mean of the fractional parts of $\log\log n$ using well-chosen limits allows a similar claim-- that the mean of $\log\log n$ (and hence of $\log\log n$ itself) is infinitely often above and below 1/2, or

$$(1)\hspace{10mm}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n-a}^N \{\log\log n \} =\pm\Omega(1/2)$$

We can express the sum in large particular bites as

$$ \sum_{e^{e^k}\le n< e^{e^{k+\delta}}} (\log\log n - k) $$

skipping as many values of $n$ as necessary to avoid complex numbers.

Then: $ k \leq \log\log n< k+\delta$ for each $n$ in the interval.

Then we can pass to the integral

$$I(k,\delta) =\int_{e^{e^k}}^{e^{e^{k+\delta}}}(\log\log x - k) ~dx $$

$$ =x\log\log x -li(x)-kx\vert_{e{e^k}}^{e^{e^{k+\delta}}}.$$

Using small k, limits I get for $I(\delta)/(e^{e^{k+\delta}}-e^{e^k})$ are

$$\lim \delta\to 0= 0^+; \lim \delta\to 1= 1.$$

Because the summand is increasing on the given intervals the mean must oscillate within the limits $(0,1].$

It seems at least plausible that the mean oscillates in a wider range than the mean for $\{\log n\}.$ Here is a plot of $(1)$ to about $n=2000$.

[image]

I have left out the messy limit calculation so the question is:

> Assuming the limits are valid, is this reasoning okay?