# Find a continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$ so that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (b_n-f(a_n)) = 0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation, continuity

> Let $a_n$ be the fractional part of $\ln n$ for $n\ge 1$. Let $b_n = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}n$. Find a continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$ so that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (b_n-f(a_n)) = 0$.

Let $\langle x\rangle$ denote the fractional part of the real number $x$. I know that if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists, then it equals $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n$. Let $e^k\leq n < e^{k+1}$ for some $k\ge 0$. Then $a_n = \langle \ln (e^k \cdot \dfrac{n}{e^k})\rangle = \ln n - k$. When $n=1$, $a_n=0=b_n$. When $n=2$, $a_2 = \langle \ln 2\rangle \approx 0.69$, $b_2 = \dfrac{a_2}2$. We need to approximate $a_n$ and $b_n$ somehow. Note that $a_n = \ln n - k\Leftrightarrow e^k \leq n < e^{k+1} < \lfloor e^{k+1}\rfloor + 1 \Leftrightarrow \lceil e^k\rceil \leq n\leq \lfloor e^{k+1}\rfloor$. In this case, we have $nb_n = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \sum_{j=\lceil e^i\rceil}^{\lfloor e^{i+1}\rfloor} (\ln j -i) + (n-\lceil e^k\rceil + 1)(\ln n - k) = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} -i(\lfloor e^{i+1}\rfloor - \lceil e^i\rceil + 1)+\ln \prod_{j=\lceil e^i\rceil}^{\lfloor e^{i+1}\rfloor} j + (n-\lceil e^k\rceil + 1)(\ln n - k)$.

But I’m not sure how to approximate $b_n$ by a continuous function of $a_n$.

Comment: Check out achille hui's answer to the question [Mean of fractional part of $\log n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2278240/mean-of-fractional-part-of-log-n)